# One or more errors occurred during processing of command. ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: asp.net, oracle10g

i am trying to perform insert but getting this error:
[Exception: One or more errors occurred during processing of command.
ORA-00936: missing expression]

it works for select query.

```
table structure is as follow
database-oracle 10g
table name-investor_info

investor_id-number
first_name-varchar
lastname-varchar
age-number
location-varchar
contact_number-varchar
email-varchar
checked-number-number


public void insert_details(string fname,string lname, int age, string location, string contactnumber, string email)
    {
        int id = get_id()+1;
        int check=0;



        string query = "INSERT INTO INVESTOR_INFO (INVESTOR_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,AGE,LOCATION,CONTACT_NUMBER,EMAIL,CHECKED) VALUES (@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4,@val5,@val6,@val7,@val8);";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand(query,conn);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", id);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", fname);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", lname);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", age);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val5", location);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val6", contactnumber);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val7", email);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val8", check);

            command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

           // conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }//end of insert
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon in string QUERY

it should be

```
string query = "INSERT INTO INVESTOR_INFO (INVESTOR_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,AGE,LOCATION,CONTACT_NUMBER,EMAIL,CHECKED) VALUES (@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4,@val5,@val6,@val7,@val8)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon from the string query and try like below,

string query = "INSERT INTO INVESTOR_INFO (INVESTOR_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,AGE,LOCATION,CONTACT_NUMBER,EMAIL,CHECKED) VALUES (@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4,@val5,@val6,@val7,@val8)";

Always specific the schema name with table name.(schemeName.tableName)

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on Oracle for a while, but have you tried replacing the `@` with a `:` for the parameters. Refer to the following artice:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters.aspx